# Unable to retrieve response headers from file containing URLs using simple python script

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to use the following code to grab URLs from a file, then print the response headers using the script below:

```
import requests

file = open('urls.txt','r')

for url in file:
    print(url)  
    r = requests.head(url)
    print(r.headers["Server"])
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 156, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Can you all please assist?  Thanks!

Comment: maybe the file has end of line character at the end of url. I suggest using `url.strip()` instead

Comment: It would help you you put like first  5 rows of the file here as well.

Comment: this worked (see below).  Thanks you all!
r = requests.head(url.strip())

Comment: Cool, I can submit it as an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**End of line character:**

Your file `urls.txt` has end of line characters in every line. Something like this

```
www.google.com\n
https://stackoverflow.com/\n
https://github.com/\n
https://www.google.com/
```

When you read the file, the character `\n` gets read as well which is causing issue with `requests.head(url)`.

**Removing the end of line character:**

This is an easy fix. To remove end of line characters you can use python string method `.strip()` which removes the newline characters as well as leading\trailing whitespace.

Another option is to use the `splitlines()`. Which will handle EOL character for you. An example code is

```py
temp = open(filename,'r').read().splitlines()
```

Sidenode: Always use `with` clause while reading/writing file as it automatically handles the closing of file for you once you have left the scope.

```
import requests

with open("urls.txt", "r") as url_file:
    temp = url_file.read().splitlines()
    for url in temp:
        print(url)
        r = requests.head(url)
        print(r.headers["Server"])
```